# Error: ASSERTION ERROR: NgModule '[object Module]' is not a subtype of 'NgModuleType'. [Expected=> null != null <=Actual]

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, micro-frontend

this is the main.ts of the shell projet(port: 5000) that is calling the micro-front-end mfe1 (port:3000)

```
import { loadRemoteEntry } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

Promise.all([
  loadRemoteEntry('http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js', 'mfe1')
])
  .catch(err => console.error('Error loading remote entries', err))
 .then(() => import('./bootstrap'))
 .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

this is the link calling the mfe1 module app.module.html

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="../assets/angular.png" width="50"></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/flights/flights-search">Flights</a></li>

</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app-routes I'm calling it in app.module.ts in the imports RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'flights',
      loadChildren: () =>
        loadRemoteModule({
           // We don't need this anymore b/c its loaded upfront now
           // remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
          //type: 'manifest',
          remoteName: 'mfe1',
          exposedModule: './Module'
 })

    },
];
```

Every thing seems good
[this is my shell is loading the component flights_module successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV74T.png)

[but I get this error and the component is not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjQpz.png)

Answer (score 0):

shell\app.routes.ts ) missing **.then((m) => m.FlightsModule)**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';


export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'flights',
      loadChildren: () =>
        loadRemoteModule({
           // We don't need this anymore b/c its loaded upfront now
           // remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
          //type: 'manifest',
          //type: 'module',
          //remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
          remoteName: 'mfe1',
          exposedModule: './Module'
    }).then((m) => m.FlightsModule)

//import('mfe1/Module').then(m =>  m.FlightsModule)
    },
];
```